# HTML Email Template Merge field values not coming in email

Tags: trigger, email-template, html, send-email

I have below code where I have to alter merge field values with record data in a trigger.

**Apex Trigger**

```
trigger ABV_SendEmailToOwner on Form_Requests_abv__c (after update) { 
    Form_Requests_abv__c i=[select Account_abv__c , Address_abv__c , Campaign_Name__c , Product_Name_abv__c , Requested_Quantity_abv__c , Requested_To_abv__c ,Status_abv__c from Form_Requests_abv__c where id=:trigger.newMap.keySet()];
    String [] sendtoemail;
    for (Form_Requests_abv__c  o : Trigger.new) { 
        String userEmail = i.Owner.email; 
        List<ABV_Form_Request_abv__c>  ACS= [select Email_abv__c, User_ID_abv__c from ABV_Form_Request_abv__c where User_ID_abv__c =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
        if(!ACS.isEmpty()){
           sendtoemail = new string[]{ACS[0].Email_abv__c};
        }
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<string> addresses =  new List<string>(); 
        for (User u : [Select Email From User where Username = : UserInfo.getUserName()]) {     
            addresses.add('saikat.neogy@cognizant.com');
        }
        EmailTemplate templateId = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'Form Request'];
        String htmlbody= templateID.htmlvalue;
        htmlbody= htmlbody.replace('{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Account_abv__c}', o.Account_abv__r.Name);
        htmlbody= htmlbody.replace('{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Address_abv__r.Name}', o.Address_abv__r.Name);
        //subject = subject.replace('{!o.Subject}', modifiedCase.Subject);
        email.setToAddresses(sendtoemail);
        email.setHtmlBody(htmlbody);
        //email.setTemplateID(templateId.Id); 
        email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        email.setReplyTo('saikat.neogy@cognizant.com');
        email.setSenderDisplayName('Abbvie IT Team');
        email.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserID());
        /*List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
          ccTo.add(userEmail);*/
        email.setCcAddresses(addresses);
        // email.setSubject( 'Email Generated Blank Forms');
        email.setToAddresses( addresses );
        // email.setPlainTextBody( 'Please find attached forms');
        mails.add(email);
        Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    } 
}
```

Comment: are you sure that you query all the fields that you want to substitute?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code that have fix to your questions and some of the bulkifications issues:

1. Query fields before use
2. Query template only once
3. Query ABV_Form_Request_abv__c only once

---

Updated version of trigger:

```
trigger ABV_SendEmailToOwner on Form_Requests_abv__c (after update) { 
    List<ABV_Form_Request_abv__c>  ACS= [select Email_abv__c, User_ID_abv__c from ABV_Form_Request_abv__c where User_ID_abv__c =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
    List<String> recipient_address = new List<String>();
    if(!ACS.isEmpty()){
       recipient_address.add(ACS[0].Email_abv__c});
    }
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List<Form_Requests_abv__c> queried_names_data = [SELECT Id, Account_abv__r.Name FROM Form_Requests_abv__c WHERE Id in :Trigger.new];
    EmailTemplate Template = [Select id,htmlvalue from EmailTemplate where name = 'Form Request' LIMIT 1];
    for (Form_Requests_abv__c  o : queried_names_data) { 
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<string> addresses =  new List<string>(); 
        String htmlbody= Template.htmlvalue;
        htmlbody= htmlbody.replace('{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Account_abv__c}', o.Account_abv__r.Name);
        htmlbody= htmlbody.replace('{!Form_Requests_abv__c.Address_abv__r.Name}', o.Address_abv__r.Name);
        email.setToAddresses(sendtoemail);
        email.setHtmlBody(htmlbody); 
        email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        email.setReplyTo('saikat.neogy@cognizant.com');
        email.setSenderDisplayName('Abbvie IT Team');
        //email.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserID());
        email.setCcAddresses(addresses);
        ////email.setToAddresses( addresses );//NOT really needed as well as you set target object Id
        mails.add(email);
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
```